# Como passar o resultado de uma Query (a tabela que é gerada pela consulta) no Postgresql usando a ferramenta Pgadmin para o Excel?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, microsoft-excel, pgadmin

Sou novo na programação e estava me questionando se era possível exportar o resultado de uma consulta no PostgreSQL para o Excel.
Eu cliquei no ícone de download na tabela gerada para ver o que aconteceria :
[imagem com a consulta exemplo e o botão mecionado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WTH1.png)

Isso me gerou um arquivo em ".csv", porém ao abrir o arquivo pelo Excel, os resultados das linhas estavam todos em uma única célula e separados por vírgula (,).

Resultado obtido : [imagem com resultado obtido](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1TZM.png)
Resultado esperado :[imagem com resultado esperado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnasu.png)

Supondo que eu tenha que fazer isso com uma tabela que tenha dezenas de linhas e/ou colunas, seria extremamente trabalhoso separar esses resultados manualmente. Isso me gerou duas dúvidas :

**1.Existe outra maneira de exportar o resultado pelo próprio PgAdmin para o Excel, evitando essa separação apenas por vírgula ou qualquer outro caracter que seja, deixando o resultado mais amigável?**

**2.Por acaso, o próprio Excel possui um mecanismo para facilitar a separação dos resultados em células diferentes?**

Comment: No Excel se define se o csv está com vírgula ou ponto e vírgula.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.